# Can I install Windows 10 on new laptop after formatting previous laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, license-key

Recently I got a new laptop, and I want to move the windows license from my previous laptop. The windows installed on my old laptop is the retail version of windows 8.1 and upgraded to windows 10. Is it possible to move the license? Or I need to purchase another license for the new laptop?

Comment: Your Windows license cannot be moved to new hardware.  You can install the Windows 8.1 license to new hardware then pay to upgrade to Windows 10

Comment: If you can find the product key of your copy of Windows and then deactivate it on your old system, yes you should be able to do this. A program I've used previously is RWeverything. It's worth trying but then again I'm not entirely certain

Answer (score 0):

With the Windows 10 Anniversary update, it is possible to link and transfer a license using a Microsoft account.  To check if your license is linked to your account, just open up the settings, check under "Update and Security" > "Activation".  Once your license is linked, you should be able to log in on the other computer after windows has been installed, and then use the same menu to move your license to the new installation.

This is more made for desktop users who change motherboards, but I would suspect that this also works for going from one laptop to the other.  Just keep in mind that this will deactivate the old installation

This page should help you through the process:
http://www.windowscentral.com/how-re-activate-windows-10-after-hardware-change